# Unable to run feature when tests runner and step definitions are added

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, bdd

I am unable to run this feature. Please see screenshot below:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/main/resources/features", glue = {"stepDefinition"})
public class RunCukeTest {
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub.

Comment: Please refer to: https://github.com/shafiqahmedkhan/APIFramework

Comment: Move resources to test root like this: https://i.imgur.com/iK5KUT5.png.

Comment: I have done this but my feature is still not running: https://imgur.com/a/wSj1tda

Comment: Use this configuration: https://i.imgur.com/OR9qwut.png.

Comment: So sorry I have tried that configuration but it does not work for me :-( https://imgur.com/4qLktVq

Comment: Make sure JDK is specified: https://i.imgur.com/DlTnCbE.png
https://i.imgur.com/TiFtoZw.png
https://i.imgur.com/tPYsa2l.png. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#define-sdk.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you so much. I have been stuck on this issue for days and I could not see any solutions anywhere online. Thanks again.